# Spark Sql 2.3 - DataFrame - SaveMode.Append - issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Can you please suggest if the below approach is correct ? I am new to Spark, i want to insert data to existing table.

```
    Dataset<Row> logDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

    if (spark.catalog().tableExists("mylogs")) {
      logDataFrame.write().mode("append").insertInto("mylogs");// exception

    } else {
        logDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("mylogs"); // This is working fine
    }

    Dataset<Row> results = spark.sql("SELECT count(a1) FROM mylogs");
```

Getting below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'InsertIntoTable LogicalRDD [a1#4, b1#5, c1#6, d1#7], false, false, false;;
'InsertIntoTable LogicalRDD [a1#4, b1#5, c1#6, d1#7], false, false, false
+- LogicalRDD [a1#22, b1#23, c1#24, d1#25], false

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$3.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$3.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:350)
```

**Edited code as per the comments:**

```
    Dataset<Row> logDataFrame = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

    if (sparkSession.catalog().tableExists("mylogs")) {
        logDataFrame.registerTempTable("temptable");
        sparkSession.sql("insert into table mylogs select * from temptable");
       //logDataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("mylogs");
    } else {
        logDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("mylogs");
    }

    Dataset<Row> results = sparkSession.sql("SELECT count(a1) FROM mylogs");
```

getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: unresolved operator 'InsertIntoTable LogicalRDD [a1#4, b1#5, c1#6, d1#7], false, false, false;;
'InsertIntoTable LogicalRDD [a1#4, b1#5, c1#6, d1#7], false, false, false
+- Project [a1#22, b1#23, c1#24, d1#25]
   +- SubqueryAlias temptable
      +- LogicalRDD [a1#22, b1#23, c1#24, d1#25], false

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:91)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it helps somebody, need to check if 'mylogs' table exists, otherwise if we try to use 'Append' key directly at runtime it throws exception 'mylogs' table doesn't exits.

And No need to shuffle around with 'temp' tables.

```
    logDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

    if (spark.catalog().tableExists("mylogs")) {
        logDataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("mylogs");
    } else {
        logDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("mylogs");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first register your dataframe as tempTable

```
logDataFrame.registerTempTable("temptable")
```

then replace your exception statement with

```
sqlContext.sql("insert into table mylogs select * from temptable"")
```

Comment: registerTempTable is a deprecated method, changed the code as below:    if (sparkSession.catalog().tableExists("mylogs")) {
            logDataFrame.registerTempTable("temptable");
            sparkSession.sql("insert into table mylogs select * from temptable");
        }

Comment: are you sure that you commented       logDataFrame.write().mode("append").insertInto("mylogs");// exception
line?

Comment: just fyi, my gradle dependency : compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.0'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SparkSession API to create a Spark Dataset from the text file.

From the data sample you have provided in the comments i have created a POJO called Log

```
public class Log implements Serializable{

    private String col1;
    private String col2;
    private String col3;
    private String col4;
    private String col5;
    private String col6;
    private String col7;

    // getters and setters here

}
```

Using this, I have applied flatmap to convert the lines of log to Log objects.

```
public class LogToDataset {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Log Job").master("spark://localhost:7077")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<String> textDF = spark.read()
                .text("C:\\Users\\log4jFile.txt")
                .as(Encoders.STRING());
         JavaRDD<Log> logRDD = textDF.toJavaRDD().map(line -> {
             String[] data =line.split(" ");
             Log log = new Log();
             log.setCol1(data[0]);
             log.setCol2(data[1]);
             log.setCol3(data[2]);
             log.setCol4(data[3]);
             log.setCol5(data[4]);
             log.setCol6(data[5]);
             log.setCol7(data[6]);

             return log;
         });

         Dataset<Row> logDataset = spark.createDataFrame(logRDD, Log.class);
        logDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("hivelogtable");
         logDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("logtable");
         spark.sql("select * from logtable").show();
    }

}
```

Now, you should be able to insert the data into the table using the `insertInto()` or `saveAsTable()` as mentioned by others in their comments.

Here is the sample data which was used to test this code

```
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512] 
10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512]
```

Final Output:

This is the output when i queries the hive table.

```
+-----+------------+-----+-----+----+------------+-------------+
| col1|        col2| col3| col4|col5|        col6|         col7|
+-----+------------+-----+-----+----+------------+-------------+
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
|10-16|14:45:08.117|11342|30575|   V|Musicplayer:|[Coming::512]|
+-----+------------+-----+-----+----+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Have already tried these options : save a Dataset using the SaveMode or you can create a temp table and runa SQL query, please refer my post for the edited section

Comment: can  you please elaborate, i am getting error 'inputpath' file not found, where we need to write it before ? : spark.read().option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
                .json("inputpath");

Comment: looks like Schema merging is not allowed by default ? i have tried to enable it, still not working

Comment: inputpath is the path where your json file is located.

Comment: i don't have json file, do we need to create it ? i receive a text file and am loading it in this way,  sparkContext.textFile(filePath, 1).toJavaRDD();

Comment: How does your text file looks?

Comment: it's a typical log4j message, this is one of the lines of log text file, 10-16 14:45:08.117 11342 30575 V Musicplayer: [Coming::512]

Comment: Actual issue is with insertInto(), I tried all the options, none of them are working, please refer my main post. Can you please show me how your code works with insertInto() ?

Comment: @Kumar this is a tested and working code in my spark cluster. I am using Spark 2.1.0. I have also tested with 2.3.0.

Comment: For me, flow is not proceeding further beyond this line, it's stuck here, i guess it's expecting hivelogtabe to exits, so that data can be appended to it : logDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("hivelogtable");

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: How are you submitting the job? Are you seeing any logs rolling in the YARN while the job is stuck.

Comment: it's not throwing any exception, it's just hung there, no progress after that. No logs in the console after this line: logDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto("hivelogtable");